# How to open the built-in image gallery programmatically inside an application in BlackBerry?

Tags: blackberry, gallery

I want to open the default image gallery inside my application, just like the way its done in the Facebook app for BlackBerry. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't know if you can invoke the default gallery. You could either use [net.rim.device.api.ui.picker.FilePicker](http://docs.blackberry.com/en/developers/deliverables/11945/File_picker_925606_11.jsp) since 5.0 or implement your own gallery [like this](http://www.id-snippet.com/50801/imagepickerdialog-blackberry/)